# React get specific property values from an object using strings in an array as property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, properties

I am having an issue with getting the property values from an object using strings in an array as property names in React. Is there a way I can retrieve these values using the array?

Here is some of my code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="dynamicTable">
        {
          this.state.people.map((item, i) => {

            return (
              <div id={item.name} className="tableRowDiv">
              {
                this.props.tableArray.map((attribute, j) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="tableDataDiv">
                      {item.(this.props.tableArray[j])} //ISSUE
```

**ISSUE: This is the line that I believe 
    needs the help.  I would like to call the property from "item" based on the property name specified in the prop array**

```
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              }
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

People.propsTypes = {
  tableArray: React.PropTypes.array,
};
```

here is the array I am using as a prop of my component:

This is an example of what the objects look like:

```
[
  [
    'name': 'bobby',
    'height': '55',
    'hair': 'brown'
    'birthday': '01011970',
    'car': 'honda'
    'weight': '130',
    'favoriteFood': 'pizza'
  ],
  [
    'name': 'mary',
    'height': '60',
    'hair': 'brown'
    'birthday': '10141990',
    'car': 'ford'
    'weight': '160',
    'favoriteFood': 'pasta'
  ],
  [
    'name': 'jane',
    'height': '50',
    'hair': 'blonde'
    'birthday': '03241980',
    'car': 'jeep'
    'weight': '140',
    'favoriteFood': 'chicken'
  ],
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `item[this.props.tableArray[j]]` should work.  However `item[attribute]` looks like it would do the same thing.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks!